# Magento2 - Call to the empty Gift message object causes the observer class to fail

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I'm trying to edit an associative array containing order info.

This array for our backend application gets created under sales_order_place_after event once the order is placed .Everything works as expected except when the order is placed with empty gift message.

Another event `sales_order_save_after` being used to only fetch the gift message fails when the order is placed without any optional gift message.

Order gets placed successfully, and the second observer class gets the control but fails when the execution reaches this line of code `!empty($this->_orderGiftRepo->get($order->getId()))` Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several hours of research and experimenting resulted in resolving the issue with the order without a gift message on it. As I'm sure it would help those who may find this issue, I would answer my own question. The most useful information is that `$this->_orderGiftRepo->get($order->getId())`will throw an exception in case of orders placed with the empty gift message. To have handled this exception like `try {
            // Magento\GiftMessage\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $_orderGiftRepo
            $gift_object  = $this->_orderGiftRepo->get($order->getId());
            $gift_message = $gift_object->getMessage();
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            // Do nothing. No gift message specified. Valid scenario.
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->debug("Empty Gift Message for this order: " . $e->getMessage());
        }`
 fixed the issue.